# How to deal with temporal correlation/trend in mppm

Tags: spatstat

Good day,

I have been working through [Baddeley et al. 2015](http://spatstat.github.io/book.html) to fit a point process model to several point patterns using [*mppm {spatstat}*](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/mppm). 
My point patterns are annual count data of large herbivores (i.e. point localities (*x, y*) of male/female animals * 5 years) in a protected area (*owin*). I have a number of spatial covariates e.g. distance to rivers (rivD) and vegetation productivity (NDVI).

Originally I fitted a model where herbivore response was a function of rivD + NDVI and allowed the coefficients to vary by sex (see mppm1 in reproducible example below). However, my annual point patterns are not independent between years in that there is a temporally increasing trend (i.e. there are exponentially more animals in year 1 compared to year 5).
So I added year as a random effect, thinking that if I allowed the intercept to change per year I could account for this (see mppm2).

Now I'm wondering if this is the right way to go about it? If I was fitting a GAMM `gamm {mgcv}` I would add a temporal correlation structure e.g. `correlation = corAR1(form=~year)` but don't think this is possible in `mppm` (see mppm3)?

I would really appreciate any ideas on how to deal with this temporal correlation structure in a replicated point pattern with `mppm {spatstat}`.

Thank you very much

Sandra

```
# R version 3.3.1 (64-bit)
library(spatstat) # spatstat version 1.45-2.008

#### Simulate point patterns
# multitype Neyman-Scott process (each cluster is a multitype process)
nclust2 = function(x0, y0, radius, n, types=factor(c("male", "female"))) {
  X = runifdisc(n, radius, centre=c(x0, y0))
  M = sample(types, n, replace=TRUE)
  marks(X) = M
  return(X)
}

year1 = rNeymanScott(5,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=5)
# plot(year1)
#-------------------
year2 = rNeymanScott(10,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=5)
# plot(year2)
#-------------------
year2 = rNeymanScott(15,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=10)
# plot(year2)
#-------------------
year3 = rNeymanScott(20,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=10)
# plot(year3)
#-------------------
year4 = rNeymanScott(25,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=15)
# plot(year4)
#-------------------
year5 = rNeymanScott(30,0.1,nclust2, radius=0.1, n=15)
# plot(year5)

#### Simulate distance to rivers
line <- psp(runif(10), runif(10), runif(10), runif(10), window=owin())
# plot(line)
# plot(year1, add=TRUE)

#------------------------ UPDATE ------------------------#
#### Create hyperframe
#---> NDVI simulated with distmap to point patterns (not ideal but just to test)
hyp.years = hyperframe(year=factor(2010:2014),
                       ppp=list(year1,year2,year3,year4,year5),
                       NDVI=list(distmap(year5),distmap(year1),distmap(year2),distmap(year3),distmap(year4)),
                       rivD=distmap(line),
                       stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
hyp.years$numYear = with(hyp.years,as.numeric(year)-1)
hyp.years

#### Run mppm models
# mppm1 = mppm(ppp~(NDVI+rivD)/marks,data=hyp.years); summary(mppm1)
#..........................
# mppm2 = mppm(ppp~(NDVI+rivD)/marks,random = ~1|year,data=hyp.years); summary(mppm2)
#..........................
# correlation = corAR1(form=~year)
# mppm3 = mppm(ppp~(NDVI+rivD)/marks,correlation = corAR1(form=~year),use.gam = TRUE,data=hyp.years); summary(mppm3)

###---> Run mppm model with annual trend and random variation in growth
mppmCorr = mppm(ppp~(NDVI+rivD+numYear)/marks,random = ~1|year,data=hyp.years)
summary(mppm1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a *trend* in population size over time, then it might make sense to include this trend in the systematic part of the model. I would suggest you add a new numeric variable `NumYear` to the data frame (eg giving the number of years since 2010). Then try adding simple trend terms such as `+NumYear` to the model formula (this would correspond to the exponential growth in population that you observed.) You can keep the `1|year` random effect term which will then allow for random variation in population size *around* the long term growth trend.

There's no need to split the data patterns for each year into separate male and female patterns. The variable `marks` in the model formula can be used to specify any model that depends on sex.

I'm pretty sure that `mppm` with `use.gam=TRUE` does not recognise the argument `correlation` and this is probably just ignored. (It depends what happens inside `gam`).

Comment: Thank you Prof. Baddeley for your help. I have updated my script above as you suggested. I had split male and females because I could not get *marks* to work in the formula. I tried both *marks* and *'marks'* but I continue to get the following error: *invalid model formula in ExtractVars*. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. It must be a bug. Do you agree @adrian-baddeley? I have made a small correction in the `mppm` code which hopefully solves the problem with marks in the formula. You should use `marks` without any quotes. You can test this new version by installing a temporary branch of `spatstat` called "marked_mppm" (requires `devtools` package): `devtools::install_github("spatstat/spatstat", ref = "marked_mppm")`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I have updated the above script accordingly.

Comment: Dang. Yes, that's a bug. Ege's fix is correct. [The bug fix will be incorporated in the main branch of the development version of spatstat.]